# CakePHP 2.0 cannot save

Tags: cakephp, save

I'm using CakePHP 2.0, I have the following save code:

```
$to_save = array(
            'User' => array(
                'uid'=>$uid,
                'firstname'=>$firstname,
                'lastname'=>$lastname,
                'bio'=>$bio,
                'gender'=>$gender,
                'link'=>$link,
                'username'=>$username,
                'email'=>$email
            )
        );

$this->User->create();

if( $this->User->save( $to_save ) ){
    echo 'User was saved.';
}else{
    echo 'User not saved.';
}
```

But it always output 'User not saved.' Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have any validation rules in the model?

Comment: @Juhana, thanks! I removed it first and that works! :)

Comment: OK, good. I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no query errors, you probably have some validation rules in the model that prevent the data from saving. You can add `debug( $this->User->invalidFields() )` to see if and which fields fail validation.