# pass parameter from url to cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I need to send parameter from URL to cakephp controller. I have message table with two parameter 'ufrom' and 'uto'. in controller i want to save this values in message table.

I put in the URL:

```
http://localhost/ar/messages/add?ufrom=9&uto=3
```

in MessagesController i have function:

```
public function add() {

if(($this->request->query['uto'])and($this->request->query['ufrom'])){
        $this->Message->create();
        if ($this->Message->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->set('addMessage',TRUE);
            $this->set('ufrom',$this->request->query['ufrom']);
            $this->set('uto',$this->request->query['uto']);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The message could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

        $targets = $this->Message->Target->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('targets'));
}
else{
    $this->set('error',true);
}
```

}

and in add.ctp i have:

```
<?php
if(isset($error)){
  echo('error');
}
else{
  echo json_encode($ufrom);
  echo json_encode($uto);
  echo json_encode($addMessage);
}
?>
```

but when i use the above URL i see:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: ufrom [APP\View\Messages\add.ctp, line 6]null
Notice (8): Undefined variable: uto [APP\View\Messages\add.ctp, line 7]null
Notice (8): Undefined variable: addMessage [APP\View\Messages\add.ctp, line 8]null
```

and Nothing is stored in the database. I'm new in cakephp. please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here i can suggest you to use params like below

```
http://www.example.com/tester/retrieve_test/good/1/accepted/active
```

but if you need to use like this way

```
http://www.example.com/tester/retrieve_test?status=200&id=1yOhjvRQBgY
```

you can get the value like below

```
echo $this->params['url']['id'];
echo $this->params['url']['status'];
```

in your case would be like

```
echo $this->params['url']['uto'];
echo $this->params['url']['ufrom'];
```

Comment: thanks for your description but my data is not stored in the database yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394080/cakephp-2-0-cannot-save pls refer this

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass parameters to the controller action would be to simply pass them through the action as arguments like so:

```
  public function add($ufrom,$uto)
```

Your URL should look like:

```
http://localhost/ar/messages/add/9/3
```

Secondarily if the data is coming from the URL you wouldn't use this->request->data , simply :

```
$message = array("Message"=>array("ufrom"=>$ufrom,"uto"=>$uto));
$this->Message->save($message);
```